# Python: How to run tests from inside a module

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a python module with the following layout:

```
database_build/
database_build/__init__.py
database_build/some_code_file.py

database_build/tests/__init__.py
database_build/tests/test_database_build.py
database_build/tests/test_content/some_assets_here
```

`test_database_build.py` has inside of it a class:

```
class TestDatabaseBuild(unittest.TestCase):
```

which has a bunch of tests. Those tests import files from the database_build module itself, e.g. `from some_code_file import my_class`.

I want to be able to run this set of tests from the database_build directory. How do I do that? Everything I have tried from other StackOverflow questions or from the [instructions here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) do not work for me. It just says "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s".

Comment: Don't put tests in modules, put them in their own (non-module) source files.

Comment: Have you considered using [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html)?  It makes testing a pretty trivial affair.

Comment: maybe the problem is in your test name methods, can you post an extract of your `test_database_build.py` file?

Comment: Cool, I used nosetests and got it working. Thanks @jaime

Comment: Great, glad it helped you out.  There's a nice list of asserts in nose.tools also.  Very useful!